# Where can I ask about the state of new technologies?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Specifically I want to ask if there's any wireless glasses that can be used be as a computer monitor (display the same video you would see on your standard desktop PC monitor), and can't seem to find a "tech exchange". Did a lot of searching and googling. I must be blind.

Answer (score 5):

Questions that are about "what is the current" are often problematic in that all the answers get obsoleted every time there is a new current.

They also tend to get poor quality and near-spam answers.

> There's a new kickstarter with wifi VR goggles but its been suspended pending investigation on brain cancer.

This type of answer isn't that helpful and often attracts low quality answers that as a side effect of how Stack Exchange work (based on timeless good answers) get archived for perpetuity.

You may find it more useful to go to one of the sites (not within SE) that is more forum like and transient with its questions and thus able to handle the temporal *now* better.

Furthermore, such questions often take the form of "list" questions. Consider the situation where such technology *does* exist.

> I am looking for a thing where you tap it and letters appear on the screen.  Kind of like a TV Typewriter.

> You are looking for a Logitech keyboard.

> You are looking for a Epic Bluetooth Virtual Keyboard.

> I use a corded keyboard. Here's a link...

And so on. As there are countless of these products, this type of question really starts to fall apart become less and less useful to *future* readers.  Especially as some of the products may have been discontinued.

Answer (score 4):

I think the only site coming close to what you want is the [Hardware Recommendations beta](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). The problem is that recommendation questions don't do well on most sites.

From their [help](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Hardware Recommendations is a community-run website to help you find a specific product for your needs. That means you can ask for a recommendation for hardware to perform a specific task.
>
> Please note that because of the subjective nature of recommending hardware, your question must meet the [community quality guidelines](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/206/411) - please read them before posting.

Comment: Why did you change my title? I don't even understand the new title? Is that even proper English? "Where can I ask to recommend technology questions?" I want to know "Where can I ask technology questions?" I'm not wanting to recommend technology questions, or to ask someone to recommend technology questions, or whatever that new title means. I have a technology question and am wondering if there's a section for tech related questions.

Comment: This site has really gone downhill these past couple years. I can't ask a question without either having sarcastic people tearing my post apart, looking for every possible error to get distracted with, or simply just foribly altering my post into something completely unrecognizable. It's great software, but the power-users are going bananas.

Comment: Okay, but your question is very specific on the recommendation part which makes or breaks your question. That is the problem with site recommendations, it has to be as specific as possible. That is what I tried to reflect in the question title, but I messed it up. Feel free to change it as you wish.

Comment: Okay, sorry for flipping out. This site drives me bonkers sometimes. I don't need a specific device recommendation, I'm more concerned about the state of technology itself - whether or not the technology of having glasses that display wireless PC video (same video you would see on your desktop monitor) has been invented yet. It's more of "Does it exist? If so, where?" rather than "Which one should I buy?" Not sure what the best wording for that it, but I'll try to edit it.